# Using Ribbon load balancing in spring cloud and autowiring the annotated interface

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, autowired, ribbon, feign

We are new to spring-cloud and struck with `Ribbon Client` dependencies. The code is working fine with `FeignClient` but using RibbonClient annotations resulting in application start fail.please find the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
   instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tutorialspoint.banking</groupId>
<artifactId>account</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>account</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign 
  -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
 <!-- <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-ribbon -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 </project>
```

The Ribbon annotated interface.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
//@FeignClient(url="http://localhost:7000",name="customer")  //works fine
@RibbonClient(name="customer")     //Autowiring fails
public interface AccountFeign {

 @GetMapping(value="/fetchcustomerdetails/{id}")
 public Account fetchCustomerDetailsUsingFeign(@PathVariable("id") int id);

}
```

The Controller as follows.

```
@RestController
public class AccountResource {

@Autowired
AccountFeign accountFeign;   //Fails with RibbonClient annotation

}
```

We are invoking web-service in another microservice which can be seen from the attributes of FeignClient and works fine but the Autowiring of the interface fails when used with the RibbonClient annotation. can someone help us understand please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Versions 1.x and 2.x are not compatible. Let the bom manage the dependencies

Comment: @spencergibb- No luck with those versions too.

Comment: You haven't shown how you use ribbon client or said what the error is, can you update your question

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
<version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).